# Count logged in users on Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is it possible to show a count of logged in users. Within Oracle Apex using the standard

Authorization scheme

DB 11g
APEX: 4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since APEX (like any web-based system) is stateless, there isn't a clear-cut list of people who are logged in.  Someone may have accessed a page 1 second ago, then closed their browser and shut down their PC.  Are they still "logged in"?  APEX has no idea that they aren't still there.

So, I would probably go for something like this:

```
select count(*)
from APEX_WORKSPACE_LOG_SUMMARY_USR
where workspace = 'MY_WORKSPACE'
and apex_user != 'nobody'
and last_view > sysdate-15/24/60;
```

i.e. authenticated users who have viewed a page in my workspace in the last 15 minutes.